# Trying to link UIImageView to a UITableViewCell from panGestureDetected method in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView that I am able to successfully move over top of a UITableView.  Both views (i.e. the UIImageView, and the UITableView) are subviews of the parent view of the viewController.  The UIImageView I am moving using a UIPanGestureRecognizer object which then calls the method panGestureDetected.  My method for panGestureDetected looks like this:

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    _startLocation = [recognizer locationInView:_imageView];

    NSLog(@"The point is: %d", _startLocation);

    int selectedRow = [_table indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    NSLog(@"The current row is: %d", selectedRow);

    CGPoint newCenter  = _imageView.center;

    newCenter.y = [recognizer locationInView:[_imageView superview]].y;
    _imageView.center = newCenter;


}
```

The user can drag the UIImageView up and down over top of the UITableView.  However, what I would like to do is have the UIImageView "link" or "connect" with whichever UITableViewCell/row that the UIImageView is covering, or closest to.  If the UIImageView is in between two rows, the UIImageView should move to whichever row it is closest to on its own.  Here is an image of what I am talking about:

[image]

In this image, the UIImageView is closer to row 1 than row 2, so after the user removes his/her finger, the UIImageView will simply move up a little bit more, and cover up row 1, making row 1 the "active row" so to speak.

At the moment, the movement of my UIImageView, and my UITableView are completely independent of one another, but when it comes to this movement where the user is dragging the UIImageView, I want there to be a connection.  Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UITableView` method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` to determine which row at which the user stopped moving the image.  Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the cell, then the cell's center, then set the `UIImageView` center to the cell center.  Something like:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
myUIImageView.center = cell.contentView.center;
```

You could also animate the last statement so it moves to over the cell smoothly rather than jumping.  Something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    myUIImageView.center = cell.contentView.center;
}];
```

Inside of a gesture recognizer handler:

```
-(void)myGestureRecognizerHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch ([gestureRecognizer state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        // Do stuff for UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan...

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        // Do stuff for UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, e.g.,
            myUIImageView.center = touchPoint;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:

            indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
            cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
                myUIImageView.center = cell.contentView.center;
            }];
        }
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        default:
        // Do stuff for cancelled/failed/...

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply!  Where in my method would I put your block of code?  Thanks again for not just providing with the code, but an explanation as well :-)

Comment: Could you also elaborate on what the variables, getstureTableEndPoint and sourceIndexPath are?  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: You would put it in your gesture recognizer callback method when `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` then if you have been updating the frame of the image view as you have been panning along, you should just snap the image view frame to the nearest cell, so `gestureTableEndPoint` can just be the center of your image view

Comment: Updated answer to make it more clear, and also show it in the context of a gesture recognizer handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods to help you out.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

basically, whenever you finish moving the imageview, I would recommend grabbing a cell with indexPathForRowAtPoint using the new center of your image view. Then you can grab the frame for that cell with rectForRowAtIndexPath and then center your imageView in that frame.